# Php exec() not working with Ajax call

Tags: php, ajax, file, exec

Hi am not too sure why this isn't working. All am trying to do is use exec from an Ajax call to make it write to a text file.

```
function testCopy() {
        alert("Testing Copy in Background........");
        ajaxCallAsync('s3/exec_copy_call.php');
    }
```

exec_copy_call.php:(where the problem is I imagine.)

```
exec('/usr/bin/php amazon_s3_copy.php  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');
```

And inside the amazon_s3_copy.php file I have:

```
$fh = fopen('test.txt', 'w');

$str = "hello!";

fwrite($fh, $str);

fclose($fh);
```

The test.txt is in the same directory and am not getting any errors it just doesn't write to the file. Am i missing something ?

Thank you

Comment: What is `ajaxCallAsync()`?  Is the AJAX request being made at all?  What is the server's response?

Comment: have you tried without ajax call and it's working there? because exec is disabled on some hosts for security reasons.
also, why do you even need exec in your case, and don't write directly in exec_copy_call?

Comment: its just a function that takes a url makes an Async Ajax call. it works I tested it out I can get into the exec_copy_call.php file and write to the file there but i can't get to the amazon_s3_copy.php using exec()

Comment: `and am not getting any errors`.... well, it's not like you're asking for them either. Nowhere in your code I see you check the return values. We just expect everything to work, right?

Comment: Don't redirect the output, so you can see if it gets an error. Use `2>&1` so the error message will be sent to the client.

Comment: you say you don't get any errors; where did you check for them (server / php logs?) have you made sure php logs are enabled?

Comment: and yes for this particular code I could just write in exec_copy_call.php but am just using this as a test as I need to eventually make it copy files from S3 from one folder to another without making the user wait so I just wanna get working at a basic level

Comment: I tested for errors using this `exec('/usr/bin/php amazon_s3_copy.php  > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &',$output,$return);` and echoing $return and I get 0